why is the array index out of bounds the line refers email items
so when the "mailCount" increment is removed from the end of the code we get a miss match error and when we implement that it runs through the code once prompts you to log on and then gives an index of array out of bounds error. Does the "mailCount" variable need to incremented with the "newMailItem"? I'm thinking that one is an object and one is a number so we have to increment the number but in the "for next" were clearly declaring objects and it doesn't seem to have a problem with it...or maybe that's what my problem is?
tried taking "mailCount" out of it completely but that doesn't work. tried not incrementing the "mailCount" no luck. tried adding one and subtracting one from the "unRead" array to keep index within.
Sub eMailSifter()
Const olFolderInbox = 6


    Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder 'does not change error if we switch this to object
    Dim unRead As Object
    Dim att As Object
    Dim emailSubject As String
    Dim newEmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim x As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mailCount As Long

    x = Date

    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set myNameSpace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    myNameSpace.Logon
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set newEmailItem = myInbox.Items(mailCount) 'it says that the array index is out of bounds and targets         this line
    Set unRead = myInbox.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True") 'set unread equal to the count of unread e mails in     the inbox

    File_Path = "D:\Documents\Email attachments\" 'where we save the attachments

    If unRead.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "NO Unread Email In Inbox"
    Else
        For Each newEmailItem In unRead
            emailSubject = newEmailItem.Subject
    
            Select Case emailSubject    
               Case emailSubject Like "MOI"    
                Set newEmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'creates a new e mail to be sent
                newEmailItem.To = "chase.bcbengineering@gmail.com" 'who your sending it to, we will need to make dynamic (it can search many places for a client e mail)
                newEmailItem.Subject = "MOI" 'enters MOI into new e mail subject line"
        
            'below is the body of the e mail
                newEmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & "Branagan Ins here just wanted to let you know there is a new MOI" & vbNewLine & "have a great week" & vbNewLine & "Branagan Ins Services" & vbNewLine & "707-255-2500" & vbNewLine & "Marilyn Branagan" & vbNewLine & "1631 Lincoln ave, Napa CA"        
    
                If m.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each att In m.Attachments
                        att.SaveAsFile File_Path & "att.Filename" 'might need to make dynamic
                        m.unRead = False 'mark email as read
                        DoEvents
                        m.Save
                        EmailApp.Attachments.Add File_Path & "att.Filename" 'attach att to new e mail out
                        Next att
                  End If
              
                  newEmailItem.Send
              
            Case emailSubject Like "Renewal"
    
                Set newEmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'creates a new e mail to be sent
                newEmailItem.To = "chase.bcbengineering@gmail.com" 'who your sending it to, we will need to make dynamic
                newEmailItem.Subject = "Renewal" 'enters MOI into new e mail subject line"
        
            'below is the body of the e mail
                newEmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi," & vbNewLine & "Branagan Ins here just wanted to let you know your policy is renewing" & vbNewLine & "have a great week" & vbNewLine & "Branagan Ins Services" & vbNewLine & "707-255-2500" & vbNewLine & "Marilyn Branagan" & vbNewLine & "1631 Lincoln ave, Napa CA"
        
    
                If m.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each att In m.Attachments
                
                        MsgBox "you saved your attachements"
   
                        att.SaveAsFile File_Path & "att.Filename" 'might need to make dynamic
                        m.unRead = False
                        DoEvents
                        m.Save
                        EmailApp.Attachments.Add File_Path & "att.Filename" 'attach att to new e mail out
                        Next att
                  End If
              
                  newEmailItem.Send
              
                Case Else
                End Select     
        Next
        newEmailItem
    
        If newEmailItem < unRead Then ' i tried using unread + 1 and unread - 1 here thinking that would keep the index in the array but neither worked
            mailCount = mailCount + 1
        Else
            mailCount = unRead
        End If
    End If
End Sub


What is the value of mailCount when you get the error?

You don't need that line Set newEmailItem = myInbox.Items(mailCount) at the top....   You're already using a For Each loop so the counter mailCount serves no purpose

Might help to add some explanation of what the code is supposed to do - it's not clear at all what the intention is here.

"miss match error" as in "type mismatch"?
